# Integrate iAd pre-roll video integration in my app?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, iad

I want to integrate an iAd Pre-Roll video Ad to my application. When I run this application, it gives me this error:

> Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ADErrorDomain error 0.)

I want to know if this code is correct or incorrect. Thanks for your help.

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("intro", withExtension: "mp4")
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

        moviePlayer!.view.frame = view.frame

        moviePlayer!.prepareToPlay()
        view.addSubview(moviePlayer!.view!)


        moviePlayer.playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler { (error) -> Void in
            NSLog("\(error)")
            self.moviePlayer.play()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

This is one of my modified App Delegate function:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        MPMoviePlayerController.preparePrerollAds()
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to display your Pre-Roll Video Ad before your application has had any time to download it. Fire your `moviePlayer.playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler` after a few seconds or move the video to a later point in your intro so your application has time to download the ad. Check my example:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Create our MPMoviePlayerController
    var moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Preload ad
        MPMoviePlayerController.preparePrerollAds()

        // Setup our MPMoviePlayerController
        moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        moviePlayer.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func playVideoButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Add our MPMoviePlayerController to our view
        self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)

        // Path of video you want to play
        let videoURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("videoName", withExtension:"MOV")

        // Set the contents of our MPMoviePlayerController to our video path
        moviePlayer.contentURL = videoURL

        // Prepare our movie for playback
        moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()

        // Play our video with a prerolled ad
        moviePlayer.playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler { (error) -> Void in
            if (error) != nil {
                NSLog("\(error)")
            }
            self.moviePlayer.play()
        }
    }
```

Tapping the `UIButton` `playVideoButton` a few seconds after application launch will play the prerolled video advertisement and then the desired video.

Also, If you're testing on your device go to Settings>Developer>Fill Rate> and make sure it is set to 100%.

Comment: It still gives me this error: Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ADErrorDomain error 0.)"

Comment: @redstoneologistcode If you're testing on your device go to Settings>Developer>Fill Rate> and make sure it is 100%. Also, make sure you have not misspelled the name of your video or are using the wrong extension.

Comment: YOU MADE MY DAY!!! Thank you! That was the problem it was 0% Thank you sooo much!!!

Comment: @redstoneologistcode if you have further questions please post them in a new question.

Comment: I have posted the question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186245/mpmovieplayercontroller-exit-detect-movie-play-and-iad