# notification when MPMoviePlayerController.preparePrerollAds() is ready

Tags: swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, iad

I've successfully implemented preroll video ads as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173294/integrate-iad-pre-roll-video-integration-in-my-app?lq=1).

This tutorial works find with a 100% fill rate in simulator but isn't going as planned now my app is live.

Is it possible to get a notification that the prerollad is ready?

What I want to do is only have the button visible if an ad is ready to load.

This is my first post here so hopefully I have made my question clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to detect if a Pre-Roll Video Ad request has been successfully filled until you plan to play it via `yourMoviePlayer.playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler`. You could check to see if you receive an `error` once the `UIButton` is tapped and request another Pre-Roll Video Ad. **I wouldn't suggest this though**. The iAd network doesn't like when you send mass amounts of requests and could potentially lower your chance of  successfully filling your Pre-Roll Video Ad even more. There's also the problem with never receiving a Pre-Roll Video Ad because the user is located in an unsupported country. Limiting functionality based on the display of an ad is not the best approach due to the unreliable nature of ads being delivered.

```
    yourMoviePlayer.playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler { (error) -> Void in
        if (error) != nil {
            NSLog("\(error)")
            // Request another ad
            MPMoviePlayerController.preparePrerollAds()
        }
        else {
            self.yourMoviePlayer.play()
            // Perform desired button action
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this.  I like a 'there is no way to do this' as it saves me trying to get it to work!  That problem was in my app the screen that was preparing a preroll was app didn't deinit like I wanted to I was probably sending more requests that I should have been which was probably the problem and I'm fixing in update.  thank you